# How can it be proven using the Monotone Convergence Theorem that an integral and a limit can be interchanged?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that a limit can be interchanged with a double integral. This is what I am starting with:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(xy)^{n}}dxdy$$

I want to show, using only the Monotone Convergence Theorem, that the above is equal to

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(xy)^n}dxdy$$

Is this possible? And if so, how can I show it?

Comment: You can certainly apply it with the measure $\mathrm d\mu(x,y)=\mathrm d x\mathrm dy$ on $(0,1)^2$ and the non-decreasing sequence of nonnegative functions $f_n(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^n(xy)^k$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Consider the sequence $$f_N :[0,1]\times[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}, \text{ }(x,y)\longmapsto\sum\limits_{n=0}^N (xy)^n.$$

Then, for each $N\in\mathbb{N}_0$, the function $f_N$ is measurable and further satisfies $$0\leq f_N\leq f_{N+1}\leq+\infty,$$ i.e. the sequence is monotonically increasing.

So the Beppo Levi theorem about monotone convergence applies, and one gets that the pointwise limit function $f$  is again measurable and the limit can be interchanged with the integrals.